# Local URL rejected for Facebook app URL

Tags: facebook

I've been building a fairly simple website-based Facebook app on a 192.168 local IP address. I'm now moving my server onto a larger local network on a 172.30 IP address, but I can't change the website address in my app settings - I get the error message "This can't be a Facebook URL" and it refuses to save the new setting. Everything functions just fine on the 192.168 address for development, but this address is not accessible by the end users so it's not an option to stay on this address.

What are my options for getting some sort of address Facebook will accept?

I wonder whether appending a port number may get around Facebook's URL checking. A local DNS entry may also be an option but is more hassle than it's worth if there are other options.

Comment: Facebook doesn’t like IP addresses to be input in that field to begin with. (Guess it would not allow you to use the 192.168 again now for a new app, it just works because you made that setting a while ago when it was still possible.) Set up a local domain for testing purposes, and use that instead.

Comment: @CBroe I've just added a new "app" to my Facebook developer account to check, and it still happily accepts the 192.168 address - I suspect Facebook internally uses the private 172.16-32 range but not the 192.168 range, and that's the cause of the blocking

Comment: Might be. But I would nevertheless strongly recommend that you set up a proper host name for development anyway. Using a mere IP address can easily lead to other problems, such as with acceptance of cookies etc.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook URL is not worked in local environment.

Comment: what? you can test facebook stuff perfectly fine in a local environment - except for sharing urls, of course.